# Simplification of expressions with radicals in Maple

Tags: maple, radicals, symbolic-computation

Having for example the expression $$\frac{abc\sqrt2}{d\sqrt{ab}}$$ (which results from a sequence of manipulations), can I force Maple to write it in the form $$\frac{c\sqrt{2ab}}{d}.$$ Many might find this as being the same thing, but I prefer the second to clarify some properties easily when explaining my work.

Comment: **Hint :** Multiply by $\dfrac{\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{ab}},$ then simplify.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thanks, but can't such simplifications be done automatically by Maple, as it is the case with the `collect`commandos ?

Comment: use radnormal() function

Comment: @Martial  already did, but unfortunately not working

Comment: in my computer it works. this is a function to simplify an expression that has radical terms. You try this: radnormal(your equation,'rationalized') or rationalize(). If they dont work, I don't know other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote "for example". Does that mean that your example only has the form of your actual problem, and that say `a` and `b` are used by you here as placeholders for more involved expressions? If so, then do you know anything about their sign?

```
expr:=a*b*c*sqrt(2)/(d*sqrt(a*b));

                                         1/2
                                  a b c 2
                          expr := ----------
                                         1/2
                                  d (a b)


radnormal(expr);

                             1/2      1/2
                            2    (a b)    c
                            ---------------
                                   d

combine(simplify(expr)) assuming a>0, b>0;

                             1/2      1/2
                            2    (a b)    c
                            ---------------
                                   d

evala(expr);

                             1/2      1/2
                            2    (a b)    c
                            ---------------
                                   d

evala(Normal(expr));

                             1/2      1/2
                            2    (a b)    c
                            ---------------
                                   d

rationalize(expr);

                             1/2      1/2
                            2    (a b)    c
                            ---------------
                                   d
```

If `radnormal(expr)` does not work for you, and if the names you used are indeed unassigned in that example, then what version of Maple are you using?